# Prestashop import product in CSV by AJAX

Tags: ajax, csv, prestashop

Can I import product which are in the CSV file:

```
http://myURL/admin/import/import-product.csv
```

By an AJAX request like:

```
http://myURL/admin/index.php?controller=AdminImport&token=et05e74456z78681c60d4785eted527&import=import-product.csv
```

`?import=import-product.csv` is just an example to explain my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can import this file via commercial Prestashop module called [Import Fast](http://prestashop.butikki.dk/en/home/14-import-fast.html) with use of CRON task.

In my case it was
mydomain.com/adminXXXX/importcron.php (in this file You can setup import parameters)